# K-mode or K-prototype

Tags: clustering

I'm studying about K-mode and K-prototype but I cannot find any proper example on a very basic example of how it works contrary to K-means where there are quite a lot (like this one [description-k-means](http://mnemstudio.org/clustering-k-means-example-1.htm)).

Does anyone know a book or website which have a similar example for K-mode and/or K-prototype ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can find scala and scala/spark implementation of both algorithms on Clustering4Ever github repository. It provide also exemples with digits datasets for kmodes on sparknotebooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these methods are designed for categoricial data, you won't find visual examples as for k-means: the data is not that visual. A realistic example run will just be a boring list of updated modes / prototypes.